Violation of cosmic censorship by negative mass Schwarzschild geometry - weak or strong?
Can anyone tell me which censorship is violated by Schwarzschild geometry with negative mass? Is it weak or strong cosmic censorship? I think the weak cosmic censorship is not violated because it is asymptotically flat metric and therefore, it possesses a complete future null infinity. So it has to be the strong cosmic censorship. Also, it seems there doesn't exist any matter configuration satisfying the energy conditions that can generate a singularity of negative mass after gravitational collapse. So it has to be strong cosmic censorship. Can anyone correct me on this if I am mistaken?

You may be misinterpreting the week censorship. If the Cauchy development of the singularity extends to infinity, then this censorship is violated (the opposite of what your question suggests). The strong censorship refers to determinism, which is not violated in this solution. In simple terms, the weak censorship implies that a sufficiently remote observer must not be in the future lightcone of the singularity, but in this solution the singularity is visible from afar, hence the weak principle is violated.

Any reference in this regard?

So you are saying that there shouldn't be any timelike geodesic for an observer from far away towards the singularity?

https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/gr/gr.pdf Also the weak cosmic censorship conjecture here says it in exactly the same way I discussed it in the question.

Sure, Wiki explains this well: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_censorship_hypothesis - “The weak cosmic censorship hypothesis asserts there can be no singularity visible from future null infinity.” - This implies that a sufficiently remote observer must not be in the future light cone of the singularity, as stated in the answer. Furthermore: “The strong cosmic censorship hypothesis asserts that, generically, general relativity is a deterministic theory” - There is nothing non-deterministic in the negative mass solution. With no horizon It is even simpler that for the positive mass.

I’ve checked 6.1.5 in the linked textbook, but didn’t find any contradiction. You state, “the weak cosmic censorship is not violated because [… the] metric […] possesses a complete future null infinity.”  However the weak censorship states exactly the opposite, a singular metric must not extend to infinity without a horizon.

i see. i think i understand what you mean now.
